# Help with redirect. Page Viewer

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am building out a SharePoint Site and was creating a home page. On one of the sections in the home page I was trying to add a page viewer feature that would allow you to see another website while you were on the home page, but now every time I open my SharePoint link it redirects me to the URL that I was trying to put as part of the page viewer and takes me off my SharePoint site completely. Can anyone help me undo this?

Answer (score 1):

Append `?contents=1` to your url for your homepage.  For example, if your page is at `https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yournewsite/home.aspx`, then browse instead to `https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yournewsite/home.aspx?contents=1`.

This opens your page in "Web Part Maintenance Mode", where instead of rendering the contents of your page, it shows you a list of which webparts are on your page, and gives you the option to remove them.

Chances are, whatever page you are loading in the page viewer has its own script to "break out" of nested frames.  Likely on purpose to prevent someone from doing exactly what you are doing.  Once you remove the webpart using Maintenance Mode, you should be able to get back to editing your home page.